# React Native - adjust scrollview as keyboard shows up (ios)

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-animated

In my chat application, I am having a trouble animating scrollview(chat view) to slide up/adjust as keyboard shows up from bottom of the view.

If you have used any major chatting apps such as Messengers, WeChat, Line, etc., you will see how your chat screen goes up smoothly as keyboard shows up. Right now, I have imitated KeyboardAvoidingView and implemented something similar to that:

```
// Triggered by Keyboard.addListener("keyboardWillChangeFrame", onKeyboardChange);
  const onKeyboardChange = e => {
    if (!e) {
      //this is scroll view's contentInset.top
      setSpacing(0);
      return;
    }

    const { duration, easing, endCoordinates, startCoordinates } = e;
    let offset;
    if (startCoordinates) {
      offset = startCoordinates.screenY - endCoordinates.screenY;
    } else {
      offset = endCoordinates.height;
    }

    const spacing = offset > 0 ? offset : 0;
    if (duration && easing) {
      LayoutAnimation.configureNext({
        // We have to pass the duration equal to minimal accepted duration defined here: RCTLayoutAnimation.m
        duration: duration > 10 ? duration : 10,
        update: {
          duration: duration > 10 ? duration : 10,
          type: LayoutAnimation.Types[easing] || "keyboard"
        }
      });
    }
    //this is scroll view's contentInset.top
    setSpacing(spacing);
  };
```

As you can see, I am currently just calculating offset using event passed by KeyboardWillChangeFrame and using LayoutAnimation to animate scrollview slide up.
It works fairly well but I can still see a slight delay.

In native iOS development, it can be achieve by using [animateKeyframes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622552-animatekeyframes):

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification){
    let duration = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
    let curve = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
    let curFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let targetFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let deltaY = targetFrame.origin.y - curFrame.origin.y

    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {
        self.view.frame.origin.y += deltaY
    })
}
```

But it seems like it is not available in react native.
Is there anyway I can adjust scrollview as keyboard shows up from bottom as smoothly as possible?

Answer (score 0):

**You have to do 2 things**

1 : First use [react-native-keyboard-spacer](https://github.com/Andr3wHur5t/react-native-keyboard-spacer) to make Textinput container scroll

2 : Set offset of ChatList when keyboard show/hide

**Complete Code**

```
import React from "react";
import { View, FlatList, Text, TextInput, Keyboard } from "react-native";
import KeyboardSpacer from "react-native-keyboard-spacer";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    chat: [
      { id: 1, text: "Test1 1" },
      { id: 2, text: "Test1 2" },
      { id: 3, text: "Test1 3" },
      { id: 4, text: "Test1 4" },
      { id: 5, text: "Test1 5" },
      { id: 6, text: "Test1 6" },
      { id: 7, text: "Test1 7" },
      { id: 8, text: "Test1 8" },
      { id: 9, text: "Test1 9" },
      { id: 10, text: "Test1 10" },
      { id: 11, text: "Test1 11" },
      { id: 12, text: "Test1 12" },
      { id: 13, text: "Test1 13" },
      { id: 14, text: "Test1 14" },
      { id: 15, text: "Test1 15" },
      { id: 16, text: "Test1 16" },
      { id: 17, text: "Test1 17" },
      { id: 18, text: "Test1 18" },
      { id: 19, text: "Test1 19" },
      { id: 20, text: "Test1 20" },
      { id: 21, text: "Test1 21" },
      { id: 22, text: "Test1 22" },
      { id: 23, text: "Test1 23" },
      { id: 24, text: "Test1 24" }
    ]
  };

  scrollOffset = 0;
  keyboardHeight = 0;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.keyboardWillShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardWillShow",
      this._keyboardWillShow
    );
    this.keyboardWillHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardWillHide",
      this._keyboardWillHide
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardWillShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardWillHideListener.remove();
  }

  _keyboardWillShow = e => {
    this.keyboardHeight = e.endCoordinates
      ? e.endCoordinates.height
      : e.end.height;

    const newOffset = this.scrollOffset + this.keyboardHeight;
    this.chatList.scrollToOffset({ offset: newOffset, animated: true });
  };

  _keyboardWillHide = e => {
    const newOffset = this.scrollOffset - this.keyboardHeight;
    this.chatList.scrollToOffset({ offset: newOffset, animated: true });
  };

  handleScroll = e => {
    this.scrollOffset = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 30 }}>
        <FlatList
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          ref={ref => {
            this.chatList = ref;
          }}
          data={this.state.chat}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text style={{ padding: 20 }}>{item.text}</Text>
          )}
          onScroll={this.handleScroll}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter Message"
          style={{ padding: 20, borderTopWidth: 1, borderColor: "black" }}
        />
        <KeyboardSpacer />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**App Preview**

[image]

Comment: @Hikaru Watanabe , Updated Answer , Added sample code . Please check in applicatons like whatsapp,messanger , it is bottom textinput view which is moved not the chat list .Chat List will remain on same offset

Comment: sorry I think I have confused you. I am talking about chat screen like where you actually talk with person, not contact list. The scrollview contains conversation so it needs to move up as keyboard shows up so that user does not scrolldown to go back to where he/she was before when keyboard shows up

Comment: @Hikaru Watanabe . I am also talking about the Chat screen . Please check it again  in whatsapp . Adding whatapps app demo which i have made.  Check this [https://gph.is/g/ZnxYRkJ](https://gph.is/g/ZnxYRkJ). When you want to type and open keyboard  , The chat list will remain on same position .  The chat list will go to bottom if you add new message

Comment: https://gph.is/g/ZnxYRkJ is exactly what I want to achieve. In https://gph.is/g/ZnxYRkJ, scrollview offset seems to move as keyboard shows up. But in your AppPreview, flatlist/scrollview does not seem to adjust and that's what happened to me when i used the open source which you suggested me.

Comment: In your app preview, textinput comes up with keyboard, but scrollview contentView does not adjust.

Comment: Updated answer you can use [scrolltoend](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrolltoend) when new message added

Comment: I am not talking about when new message is added. I am talking about when keyboard shows up, I want to adjust scrollview contentView so that user can see what they saw in scrollview after keyboard showed up. This is happening in  gph.is/g/ZnxYRkJ.

Comment: @Hikaru Watanabe . Sorry for mis-understanding . Updated answer . this is my final try please check it now.

Comment: why not use scrollToEnd? just curious